# I want to make a shooting game with animate AS3, and i stuck with with this code

Tags: actionscript-3, jquery-animate

I want to improve this coding of mine but i cant find a way. so everytime i press "space" the bullet came out from the object, and if i pressed it again, the bullet that already called to the stage will reset its coordination, instead of calling another one. or can u only called one child at a time? is there any way for me to calling many child instead of just 1?

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var fl_MyInstance:bullet = new bullet();
function move(event:Event):void
{
    if(fl_MyInstance.hitTestObject(wall))
    {
        removeChild(fl_MyInstance);
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move);
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, summon);
function summon(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
    addChild(fl_MyInstance);
    fl_MyInstance.x = hero.x
    fl_MyInstance.y = hero.y
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move);
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gerak);
function gerak(e:Event):void
{
    fl_MyInstance.y += 5;
}
```

Comment: Because you have a single instance of bullet. Like, you have a stage table and a basket of apples. You took one apple and put it on the table. Whenever you address the apple, it's always the one already on the table. In order to work with multiple objects, read about **Array**s and **loops**.

Comment: thank you so much, i was wondering how to increase the amount of "Apple".

Comment: You need an **Array** of bullets rather than a variable for a single bullet. You can add and remove its elements thus increasing or decreasing the amount of bullets you manage. Also add and remove them to/from display list to actually observe them.